# i am trying to bind a jquery data grid threw NancyFX using odata

Tags: jquery, .net, datatable, odata

I am new to odata can some one send me the sample code for binding datatable using nancy and odata.
i am getting the error in

```
 obj.AsQueryable().LinqToQuerystring((IDictionary<string, object>)context.Request.Query);
```

Comment: This seems broad.  You bind he data returned by Nancy in the browser.  I would think you'd be posting JavaScript with the title you've given.

Comment: Its done the prob was, I was sending to column filter which was not really exists in object.